# std::set - correct way to implement operator <?

Tags: c++11

I have the following data with operator < implemented:

```
enum eDataSetType
{
    eData1,
    eData2
};

struct LocationData
{
    bool operator < (const LocationData& other) const
    {
        if (mFileName < other.mFileName ||
            mDataSet < other.mDataSet ||
            mChunkId < other.mChunkId ||
            mAnimIndex < other.mAnimIndex)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    eDataSetType mDataSet;
    std::string mFileName;
    Uint32 mChunkId;
    Uint32 mAnimIndex;
};
```

But when using `std::set<LocationData>::insert` I sometimes get the following message:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
---------------------------
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP120D.dll
File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtree
Line: 1795

Expression: invalid operator<

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)

---------------------------
Abort   Retry   Ignore   
---------------------------
```

Why?

Comment: Because you didn't create a proper ordering.

Comment: Your operator doesn't define an ordering. It's garbage. How do you want to order the items?

Comment: E.g. in your logic, both `(1, 0) < (0, 1)` and `(0, 1) < (1, 0)` are true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use the lexicographical comparison provided by [std::tie](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)

```
 bool operator < (const LocationData& other) const
 {
    return std::tie(mFileName, mDataSet, mChunkId, mAnimIndex) < std::tie(other.mFileName, other.mDataSet, other.mChunkId, other.mAnimIndex);
 }
```

You can rearrange the members order to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to determine how do you want to order the items, then you have to make sure that your function provides a strict weak order, which it's not what your function does.

For example, you can rewrite your function like this:

```
friend bool operator < (const LocationData& a, const LocationData& b) const
{
    if ( a.mFileName < b.mFileName )        // sort by filename...
        return true;
    else if ( a.mFileName > b.mFileName )
        return false;
    else {
        if ( a.mDataSet < b.mDataSet )      // then by DataSet...
            return true;
        else if ( a.mDataSet > b.mDataSet)
            return false;
        else {
            if ( a.mChunkId < b.mChunkId )
                return true;
            else if ( a.mChunkId > b.mChunkId )
                return false;
            else
                return a.mAnimIndex < b.mAnimIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `friend` since data members are public

Comment: @coincoin yes, we don't. Now, it may be interesting to investigate if it's better to remove the `friend` or to make some of the members `private`...

Comment: Ah of course, I always get so confused with operator <, I wish set used operator == instead